# Using the apply function to pandas dataframe with arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, apply

I created a function to take a column of a `string datatype` and ensure the first item in the string is always `capitalized`. Here is my function:

```
def myfunc(df, col):
     transformed_df = df[col][0].capitalize() + df[col][1:]
     return transformed_df
```

Using my function in my column of interest in my pandas dataframe:

```
df["mycol"].apply(myfunc)
```

I don't know why I get this error: `TypeError:` `myfunc() missing 1 required positional argument: 'col'`

Even adding `axis` to indicate that it should treat it `column wise`. I believe I am already passing my arguments why do I still need to specify `col` again? Correct me if I am wrong?

Your input is highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If use [`Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) then each value of Series is processing separately, so need:

```
def myfunc(val):
     return val[0].capitalize() + val[1:]
```

---

If want use pandas strings functions:

```
df["mycol"].str[0].str.capitalize() + df["mycol"].str[1:]
```

If want pass to function:

```
def myfunc(col):
    return col.str[0].str.capitalize() + col.str[1:]
```

Then use [`Series.pipe`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.pipe.html) for processing Series:

```
df["mycol"].pipe(myfunc)
```

Or:

```
myfunc(df["mycol"])
```

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for the insights. Silly me.